# Vue js rerender the same component when changing route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have one auth component that I am using both in the login and the signup route.

```
const routes = [{
  path     : '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
}, {
  path     : '/signin',
  name: 'signin',
  component: Auth
},
  {
    path     : '/signup',
    name: 'signup',
    component: Auth
  }];
```

If for example, I'm on the login page The problem is if I type something in the text inputs and go to the signup the text is still there, how I force the component to reinitialize?

Comment: if possible, provide a jsfiddle, so better help can be provided.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The better way to do this is actually to bind the routes path to the router-view's key, i.e.

```
<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
```

Doing so will force Vue to create a new instance of the component.

**EDIT**

Updated to provide a meta key you could add which would allow you to disable the reuse of components only for the routes you require. this would need refining if you wanted to work with it on routes that are more than 1 level deep - but it gives you the idea.

```js
const Foo = {
  name: 'foo',
 data () {
     return {
         inputText: '',
        }
    },
 template: `
     <div class="box">
         <h1>{{ $route.path }}</h1>
            <input type="text" v-model="inputText">
        </div>
    `,
}

const Baz = {
  name: 'baz',
 data () {
     return {
         inputText: '',
        }
    },
 template: `
     <div class="box">
         <h1>{{ $route.path }}</h1>
            <input type="text" v-model="inputText">
        </div>
    `,
}

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo, meta: { reuse: false }, },
  { path: '/bar', component: Foo, meta: { reuse: false }, },
  { path: '/baz', component: Baz },
  { path: '/bop', component: Baz }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  data: {
    key: null,
  },
}).$mount('#app')

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.reuse === false)) {
    app.key = to.path
  } else {
    app.key = null
  }
  next()
})
```

```css
#content {
    position: relative;   
  height: 200px;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
    <router-link to="/baz">Go to Baz</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bop">Go to Bop</router-link>
  </p>
  <div id="content">
      <router-view :key="key"></router-view>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ key }}</pre>
</div>
```

This then allows you to combine your router-view with Vues transition system so it becomes pretty awesome!

Comment: The problem with this approach that this will be globally to all components.

Comment: if you use a dynamic key then you can control how "global" it is, will update above

Comment: updated above to allow enabling of this feature only on desired routes, via the routes meta param

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) attribute to indicate vue to rerender some elements instead of reusing them.

e.g. you have an `<input/>` in your `Auth` component which you want to rerender under different routes, add a `key` data prop to `Auth`, use `<input :key="key"/>` in the template. In your case here,

```
data() {
    key: this.$route.path
}
```

may be a good choice.

Comment: lol - I literally was pasting my answer as you posted! Upvoted you - but I did also nail the fiddle! :)

Comment: @GuyC Well reading this the word 缘分 comes to my mind. Also I always quite respect those who write long answers with detailed, real-world examples with perfection...

Comment: thanks dude - impressive how we both answered 5 hours later with the same answer!

Answer (score 2):

vuejs caches rendered component. you don't provide `Auth` component code, but i think the following helps you.

```
<template>
     <input type="text" ID="username" v-model="usernameinput">
     <!-- other text boxes and inputs -->
</template>
export default {
    name: 'Auth',
    //component code .....
    data: function() {
        return {
            usernameinput: '',
            //and other stuff
        }
    },
    watch: {
        // call method if the route changes
        '$route': 'reInitialize'
    },
    methods: {
        reInitialize: function() {
            this.usernameinput = '';
            //and so on
        }
    },
    //remainig component code
}
```

also there is another posibilty, may be you are using dynamic components and `keep-alive` is true.

Comment: No I am not using keep alive just regular component

Comment: so, the `watch` and `methods` part should be the way.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only way?

Comment: No! :-) I'm not sure, but this is what i use

Comment: Ok I will wait for more answers before marking yours. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should watch route params and when it changes, re-execute to fetch data.
Example

```
created() {
// watch the params of the route to fetch the data again
this.$watch(
  () => this.$route.params,
  () => {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  // fetch the data when the view is created and the data is
  // already being observed
  { immediate: true }
)
```

},

More info at https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation

Comment: It does not answer the question. The code snippet you shared is about fetching data while the component is loading. It's not about the case when the component wasn't unmounted on route change (the question)