# VueJS Force Update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle

I'm having an issue with data rendering properly within a Vue component. We have a scenario where we update the route, but it loads the same component. When this happens, it appears that the lifecycle hooks don't run. I assume that this is intentional and that Vue is trying to be performant.

I'm looking for a way to force the component to re-render giving me access to the lifecycle hooks again.

Comment: are you sure neither `beforeRouteEnter` nor `beforeRouteUpdate` solve your problem ? (assuming you use vue-router)

Comment: See http://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: The article [michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render](http://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/) runs out of steam at the end, and does not show how to do it in a routing scenario. I would suggest this question [Vue js rerender the same component when changing route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884023/vue-js-rerender-the-same-component-when-changing-route) is a better guide.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Thanks for sharing that link, the solution from that question worked wonderfully!