# I'm losing data after clicking on About page in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a Vue router installed and two pages: `Home` and `About`.
All is working, but when I click to `About` page and then back, data from `Home` page is gone. Page not reloading, I'm just moving between routed pages. Props are passed to the component.
Where is a mistake? Why data doesn't save in component after clicking `About` page?

Comment: Did you tried the [keep-alive](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view) ?

Comment: keep-alive worked for ```Home``` page, thanks! But I also need some data to be displayed on ```About``` page. Using vue devtools I can see, that when I click on ```About``` page props are gone from component... Please help!

Comment: Use vuex store these purpose. https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Try using router's key prop to force Vue to create a new instance of the component to see if that is the problem. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884023/vue-js-rerender-the-same-component-when-changing-route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. `Vuex` was used.