# Cannot copy props to data in child component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a child component `SecondPage.vue`. Props are passed to this component from parent component. Props are passed to child on click event. Then I'm trying to copy these props to data in `SecondPage.vue`. But when I use vue devtools, I can see, that data in child component is clear.

According to devtools, after click props in child are provided, but data (`genQ`, `isA`) is empty.
Where is the mistake?

SecondPage.vue

```
export default {
    name: "SecondPage",
    props: ["generalQuestInfo", "isActive", "getIconClass"],
    data: function(){
        return {
            genQ: Object.assign({}, this.generalQuestInfo), //empty in devtools
            isA: this.isActive  //empty in devtools
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. What is the purpose of assigning props to data? Why don't you use props directly?

Comment: that's because I need component ```SecondPage``` to be displayed on routed page, but when I click that page, props are cleared. And now I'm trying to save these props to data in child component and use it instead props. And I hope this could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240303/im-losing-data-after-clicking-on-about-page-in-vue

Comment: Do you use vuex? That will solve your issue.

Comment: no, I don't. I will try, thx.To be honest, I thought this could be done without using vuex)

Comment: The code you have provided is fine, but without knowing the details of how exactly you are passing the data to the child component we can't do much to help you. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vuex` store solved my problem!!!