# Problems with routes - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tell u my problem.
At first I want to say that a lifehook is created in all routes in this `console.log ('Test');` stands.

I have 5 routes.

- Home
- Test1
- Test2
- Test3
- Cart

The problem with this is when I click Home or Cart it work. When I switch from Home to Test1, Test1 is also executed. If I switch from Test1 to Test2 or Test3 the Lifehook is not executed. These 3 (Test1, Test2 and Test3) will only be executed if I was on Home or Cart before.

Why isn't lifehook running on these 3 routes added through the API?

https://hasteb.in/dejezebu.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The life cycle hook isn't kicked off because when switching in between the three routes (Test1, Test2, Test3), the component (`Category.vue`) isn't re-rendered.

In order to force Vue to create a new instance of the component `Category.vue`, you can bind the route's path to the router-view's key as stated in the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890724/10082744