# Print a page with details from Json file in Vue

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I am able to loop and print all data from a local json file `games.json` like the one below:

```
{
  "games": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "foo",
    "title": "The Foo Game",
    "image": "/img/games/Foo",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "bar",
    "title": "The Bar Game",
    "image": "/img/games/Bar.png",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "slug": "hello",
    "title": "The Hello Game",
    "image": "/img/games/Hello",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "slug": "world",
    "title": "The World Game",
    "image": "/img/games/World",
  }
]}
```

In the list page in the `v-for`loop I gave them all a link with a `slug` to their detail page (`GameDetail.vue`):

```
<template>
  <div>
     <div v-for="game in games" :key="game.id">
      <div v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + game.image + ')' }"></div>
      <router-link :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/games/` + game.slug + `/`" >
          <div>
            <p v-html="game.title"></p>
          </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import json from '../../assets/data/games.json'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        games: json.games,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But I couldn't print the details.
How should I setup `GameDetail.vue` to print just one Game, lets say if the path is `/en/game/foo` or `/en/game/bar`

*Edit*

This was my attempt for `GameDetail.vue`:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div v-for="game in getData($route.params.slug)" :key="game.slug">
    {{ game.title }}
    {{ game.image }}
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import json from '../../assets/data/games.json'
  export default {
    props: ['slug'],
    data() {
      return {
        games: json,
        playerOptions: {
          // videojs options
          muted: false,
          language: 'en',
          height: '600',
          volumeControl: false,
          playbackRates: [0.7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
          sources: [{
            type: "video/mp4",
            src: "/mov/CockroachRacers.mp4"
          }],
          poster: "/mov/CockroachRacers.jpg",
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
    getData(slug) {
      let data = this.games
      data.filter(item => {
        return item.slug == slug
      })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: At first sight, your code appears to be working. Did you check the developer console if the json is loaded correctly? You can use the  'Vue Dev Tools' browser extension to debug you components/app.

Comment: @Daantje Thank you for the comment. The part I shared works. I guess I should have been clearer. Sorry about that. I need a new page, thets say GameDetail.vue where I can print the detail for each game. There is a router-link in the ListPage that links to a path with each games slug. I've not be able to manage that. This page I need should filter the to data with the correspondent slug. Hope this clears my question.

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890724/536590

Comment: consider this as a two pages. the first one lists all titles of the data from the json file. when clicked you get the detail of the that title. like a blog maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I mannaged to do it like this :

I added a method

```
methods: {
    filteredGame(slug) {
        return this.games.filter(game => game.slug === slug)
      }
}
```

And added a v-for in the template

```
<div v-for="game in filteredGame(slug)" :key="game.id">
    <p v-html="game.title"></p>
    <p>{{ game.slug }}</p>
    <p>{{ game.image }}</p>
</div>
```